# How to set rootdir and outdir when the source code is in multiple folders?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using typescript in my node project. Earlier I had a folder structure shown below:

```
    node_modules
    src
       -Models
       -Routes
       -Middlewares
       -Controllers
       -index.ts
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
```

In the above case, all my logics was inside a single root folder `src`. So, I passed `outDir: './dist'` and `rootDir: './src'`. When the code compiled using `tsc` then a dist folder was created and files and folder structure similar to `src` could be seen in `js` format.

Now due for some reason I want to change my folder structure as below:

```
  node_modules
  Redlof
     -index.ts
     -Modules
           -User
               -Controllers
               -Routes
               -Validation
  Engine
     -Middlewares
     -Helpers
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
```

What should be the value for `outDir` and `rootDir` in this scenario?
Please guide me.

Comment: Presumably you're asking because you tried a few things that _didn't_ work, right?  `rootDir: '.'`, `rootDir: './Redlof'`, etc.?  Those details are useful to include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Then you either want to have
a) The highers dir "." to be the "rootDir", and configure "includes" and "excludes" as needed
or
b) List all of them as "rootDirs", see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDirs

---

or c) you wand monorepo with multiple packages